# How do I send emails via msmtp from inside XEN DOM0

Tags: email, xen, msmtp

I have a XEN server with someVMs, one of them is the email server.

How do I tell DOM0 to send all root emails to my administration email, which is inside the email-VM?

I tried install `msmtpd` and added the config file `/etc/msmtprc`:

```
# A system wide configuration file is optional.
# If it exists, it usually defines a default account.
# This allows msmtp to be used like /usr/sbin/sendmail.
account default

# The SMTP smarthost
host mail.myOtherVM.de

# Use TLS on port 465
port 587
tls on
tls_starttls on

# Construct envelope-from addresses of the form "user@oursite.example"
from %U@oursite.example

# Syslog logging with facility LOG_MAIL instead of the default LOG_USER
syslog LOG_MAIL
```

But When trying to send an email with

```
echo -e "Subject: msmtp test\nhello test." | msmtp rubo77@mydomain.de
```

on my email VM I get the error:

```
lost connection after DATA from unknown[2a01:xxxx:1d02::2]
disconnect from unknown[2a01:xxxx:1d02::2] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 commands=4/6
```

(I also tried port 465 but that one is not open at all.)

Answer (score 0):

`msmtp` only works with username and password, example `/etc/msmtprc`:

```
defaults

# Use TLS on port 465
port 587
tls on
tls_starttls on

# Syslog logging with facility LOG_MAIL instead of the default LOG_USER
syslog LOG_MAIL

# Mail account
account root@yourserver.de
 
from yourserver dom0 <root@dom0.yourserver.de>

# Host name of the SMTP server
host mail.yourserver.de
 
auth on
 
user root@yourserver.de
password yourpass

account default: root@yourserver.de
```

mind to uninstall any unconfigured other MTAs and install `msmtp-mta` (which symlinks sendmail to msmtp)